# Component in ReactJS fails to load images

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, bootstrap-5

I have a few images inside a directory in my React project, and in my component, I'm trying to import all of them and display it in a carousel using Bootstrap, this is the current code:

```
import Carousel from 'react-bootstrap/Carousel';

const slideImagesFolder = '../../img/main slider/';

function importAll(r) {
  return r.keys().map(r);
}

const images = importAll(require.context('../../img/main slider/', false, /\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/));

const Items = () => {
    return images.map((e, i) => (
      <Carousel.Item key={i}><img className="slide-image d-block" src={e} alt="" /></Carousel.Item>
    ))
}


function MyCarousel() {
  return (
    <Carousel fade interval={null}>
      {/* <Carousel.Item>
        <img
          className="d-block"
          src={images[0]}
          alt="First slide"
        />
      </Carousel.Item>
      <Carousel.Item>
        <img
          className="d-block"
          src={images[1]}
          alt="Second slide"
        />
      </Carousel.Item>
      <Carousel.Item>
        <img
          className="d-block"
          src={images[2]}
          alt="Third slide"
        />
      </Carousel.Item> */}
      <Items/>
    </Carousel>
  );
}

export default MyCarousel;
```

I'm getting this error: "Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?"
I don't know why, but if I comment "<Items/>" line and uncomment the above lines, it works, I don't know why it works differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issues

The `Carousel` component attaches refs to the children it's rendering, e.g. `Carousel.Item` normally, so it can take DOM measurements to handle layout/positioning of the UI.

There are two issues with this approach:

1. `Images` isn't forwarding any ref that is passed to it.
2. `Images` would need to receive a React ref for each `Carousel.Item` component it renders. This won't work since `Image` is the only child of `Carousel` and can only forward one ref.

## Solution

Instead of creating another React component that renders the `Carousel.Item` components, just map them directly as children.

Example:

```
import Carousel from 'react-bootstrap/Carousel';

const slideImagesFolder = '../../img/main slider/';

function importAll(r) {
  return r.keys().map(r);
}

const images = importAll(require.context('../../img/main slider/', false, /\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/));

function MyCarousel() {
  return (
    <Carousel fade interval={null}>
      {images.map((src, i) => (
        <Carousel.Item key={i}>
          <img className="slide-image d-block" src={src} alt="" />
        </Carousel.Item>
      ))}
    </Carousel>
  );
}

export default MyCarousel;
```